# Select rows if combination of columns are from other data frame in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data frame with Origin, Destination and other data points. How do I efficiently select rows that have the Origin, Destination pairs of interest, i.e. I have another data frame with the pairs of interest.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Origin' : ['A','A','A','B','B','A'], 
                   'Destination' :['B','C','D','C','D','D'], 
                   'X' : ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']})


I = pd.DataFrame({'Origin' : ['A','A','B'], 'Destination' : ['B','D','C']})
```

And I would want to return back

```
  Origin Destination  X
0      A           B  a
1      A           D  c
2      B           C  d
3      A           D  f
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with default `inner` join and if only same joined columns in both `DataFrames` parameter `on` can be omit to:

```
print (pd.merge(df,I))
  Destination Origin  X
0           B      A  a
1           D      A  c
2           D      A  f
3           C      B  d
```

If need reorder columns:

```
print (pd.merge(I,df)[['Origin','Destination','X']])
  Origin Destination  X
0      A           B  a
1      A           D  c
2      A           D  f
3      B           C  d
```

If more columns with same names add `on`:

```
print (pd.merge(I,df, on=['Origin','Destination'])[['Origin','Destination','X']])
  Origin Destination  X
0      A           B  a
1      A           D  c
2      A           D  f
3      B           C  d
```

And thank you [Boud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704220/select-rows-if-combination-of-columns-are-from-other-data-frame-in-python-pandas/41704242?noredirect=1#comment70605945_41704242) for suggestion:

```
print (df.merge(I))
  Destination Origin  X
0           B      A  a
1           D      A  c
2           D      A  f
3           C      B  d
```

Comment: I can't improve on this ;-)

Comment: df.merge(I) for the win :-)